# In QML, how can I create a parent Component that takes child Component instances and puts them in the parent Components hierarchy?

Tags: qt, qml

Qt's QML has a number of widgets where you instantiate the widget and then give it an instance of a Component for it to display and use.

For example, the [`Popup` widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html) can be used like:

```
Popup { // <-- Parent Component
  Rectangle { // <-- Child Component
    width: 100;
    height: 100;
    color: 'red';
  }
}
```

How can I do this myself?  How can I write a custom QML Component that will take a child Component instance and put it beneath my tree?

If I have a silly Component like:

```
// File Parent.qml
Rectangle {
  default property var child_inst;
  width: child_inst.width + 20;
  width: child_inst.width + 20;
  color:'red';
  child_inst;  // <-- how is this done?
}
```

and used like:

```
Parent {
  Text { text: 'hello world!' }
}
```

What is the syntax or mechanism by which I can instantiate or move the `child_inst` to be a child of my `Parent`?

Comment: BTW you don't need to use the `;` in QML unless you want to pack multiple statements on the same line. Makes things a tad neater.

Comment: @dtech, Python is one of my favorite languages, so I too hate the redundancy of semi-colons ( and I hate curly braces), because they add noise.  When I started using javascript, I wrote exclusively without semi-colons, unless necessary. 
 Unfortuntely, I was burned multiple times and I just decided to use semi-colons in javascript everywhere, even though semi-colons and braces are redundant scoping information from the point of view of humans, since humans effectively ignore braces and semi-colons and just use whitespace to understand programs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wow, that's hella confusing way to put it, but if I understand correctly, you want to have children actually redirected to some other object automatically. This is possible, for example:

```
// Obj.qml
Rectangle {
  width: 50
  height: 50
  default property alias content: row.children
  Row {
    id: row
  }
}
```

and then:

```
  Obj {    
    Rectangle {
      width: 10
      height: 10
      color: "red"
    }
    Rectangle {
      width: 10
      height: 10
      color: "green"
    }
    Rectangle {
      width: 10
      height: 10
      color: "blue"
    }    
  }
```

The result is that the rgb rectangles are displayed in a row, because even though they are nested in `Obj`, they are internally delegated to the row.

Using a `default` property means that you don't have to specify it manually. Of course, if you don't want that, you can even use multiple different placeholders, for example, you can have:

```
  property alias content: contentItem.children // this is a column of contents
  property alias control: buttons.children // this is a row of buttons
```

Keep in mind that if you don't use the default property, you will have to specify the objects as a comma separated list in the case they are multiple:

```
  Obj {
    content : [
      Rectangle {
        width: 10
        height: 10
        color: "red"
      },
      Rectangle {
        width: 10
        height: 10
        color: "green"
      },
      Rectangle {
        width: 10
        height: 10
        color: "blue"
      }
    ]
  }
```

This is not necessary if it is a single object, it can be created like this:

```
  Obj {
    content : Rectangle {
      width: 10
      height: 10
      color: "green"
    }
  }
```

But you can also use a single target and have your row nest the objects externally, which can save you having to bother with the array notation and gives you more flexibility:

```
  Obj {
    content : Row {
      // bunch of stuff here
    }
  }
```

In this case, the `content` can be a simple positioned `Item`, that will serve as a placeholder, as it is the case for the popup component.

And finally, you can also use a `Loader` if you want to specify an inline component, that is one that is not defined in a dedicated QML file but using the `Component` element.

Comment: when using a `default property alias`, it's better to alias to `data` than to `children`. Thre reason is that `children` only accepts Items, it won't work with non visual objects like `Timer` or others.

Comment: That is true, even if outside of the particular usecase context.

Comment: GrecKo's comment about using .data is so important it should become part of the accepted solution!!!